# Yii2 unit testing not working properly

Tags: phpunit

When I am running yii2 unit test I am getting the following error

Fatal error: Class 'frontend\tests\unit\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the class PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase?

Comment: Thanks Jithesh for the quick reply. I have included TestCase class and it is working fine , but it is showing the above error when namespace includes in it.

Comment: How include this class and in the which file? Does this not included by default?